# WSUS - Check which computer is missing a specific update?

Tags: wsus

Is there a way to check in WSUS which computers have installed an approved update and which computers have not yet installed it? The general details show the number of computers needing and update and the number of computers which have installed the update or where the update is not applicable.

Is there a way to generate a list which lists the computers that have or have not installed the update?

Comment: did you ever looked at the updates itself? if you click on it you will see usually these information

Comment: @djdomi It doesn't seem to list the specific computers that have or haven't received a computer. Are you saying it does?